# How to zoom in responsive images on mobile devices?

Tags: css, mobile

I'd like to be able to make and image that I'm having with this `CSS`:

```
img{
  width:     100%;
  display:   block;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

zoomable, so that the user can clearly read all the text that's on it, but as of now - if a user zooms in on it, he gets a very blury image because it's being reduced in size so significantly. Is there a known solution to this?

Comment: Your original image is in high quality? if not that's going to be a problem. If it is in high quality and is being reduced in size by some 3rd party plugin you need to find that plugin and change it's settings to higher quality than it is.

Comment: @odedta yes it is in high quality. And it's not being reduced by some 3rd party plugin, it's being reduced with CSS so that it fits the screen and proportions remain the same.

Comment: If you're only using that CSS on an image it should not be reduced by size, only proportions, the quality should stay the same.
What values are you using on the viewport metatag?

Comment: @odedta I'm using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Weird, do you mind providing a link? i've never come across this issue, especially now that's i'm working on an app that is doing a lot of sizing for images.

Comment: @odedta I am kind of making it on a localhost so at the moment there is no link :)

Comment: Then recreate the problem on jsfiddle, otherwise it's really hard to help you.

Comment: Maybe you use a php script like responsive images? Upload your files to another server. If you have still the problem it isn't a script. Images really full HD? We need an example please.